# Why do I get the "Unhandled exception type IOException"?

Tags: java, stdin, readline, ioexception

I have the following simple code:

```
import java.io.*;
class IO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
       BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));    
       String userInput;    
       while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(userInput);
       }
    }
}
```

And I get the following error message:

```
----------
1. ERROR in io.java (at line 10)
    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Unhandled exception type IOException
----------
1 problem (1 error)roman@roman-laptop:~/work/java$ mcedit io.java
```

Does anybody have any ideas why? I just tried to simplify the code given on the sum web site ([here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html)). Did I oversimplify?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You should add "throws IOException" to your main method:

`public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {`

You can read a bit more about checked exceptions (which are specific to Java) in [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html).

Answer (score 55):

Java has a feature called "checked exceptions". That means that there are certain kinds of exceptions, namely those that subclass Exception but not RuntimeException, such that if a method may throw them, it *must* list them in its throws declaration, say: void readData() throws IOException. IOException is one of those.

Thus, when you are calling a method that lists IOException in its throws declaration, you must either list it in your own throws declaration or catch it.

The rationale for the presence of checked exceptions is that for some kinds of exceptions, you must not ignore the fact that they may happen, because their happening is quite a regular situation, not a program error. So, the compiler helps you not to forget about the possibility of such an exception being raised and requires you to handle it in some way.

However, not all checked exception classes in Java standard library fit under this rationale, but that's a totally different topic.

Answer (score 15):

Try again with this code snippet:

```
import java.io.*;

class IO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        try {
            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));    
            String userInput;    
            while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(userInput);
            }
        } catch(IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Using `try-catch-finally` is better than using `throws`. Finding errors and debugging are easier when you use `try-catch-finally`.

Answer (score 0):

Reading input from keyboard is analogous to downloading files from the internet, the java io system opens connections with the source of data to be read using InputStream or Reader, you have to handle a situation where the connection can break by using IOExceptions

If you want to know exactly what it means to work with InputStreams and BufferedReader [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXsZHUtmNs4) shows it

Answer (score 0):

add "throws IOException" to your method like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws  IOException{

        FileReader reader=new FileReader("db.properties");

        Properties p=new Properties();
        p.load(reader);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the Error even though i was catching the exception.

```
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("kitten.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("blabla", "Error", e);
        finish();
    }
```

Issue was that the IOException wasn't imported

```
import java.io.IOException;
```