# Unhandled Exception Type IOException

Tags: java, file-io, io, ioexception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get the “Unhandled exception type IOException”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305966/why-do-i-get-the-unhandled-exception-type-ioexception)

I'm trying to solve Euler #8 using the following algorithm. Problem is, whenver I modify the line I have the giant comment on, the error `Unhandled Exception Type IOException` appears on each line that I've marked with the comment `//###`.

```
private static void euler8()
{   
    int c =0;
    int b;
    ArrayList<Integer> bar = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
    File infile = new File("euler8.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream(infile), //###
                            Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        while((c = reader.read()) != -1) { //###
          char character = (char) c;
          b = (int)character;
          bar.add(b); /*When I add this line*/
        }
    reader.close(); //###
}
```

Comment: Read the [Exceptions Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) and then use that knowledge to either wrap the code in a try/catch or throw the exception -- your choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `IOException` is a *checked exception*, which means you either need to catch it, or declare that your method will throw it too. What do you *want* to happen if the exception is thrown?

Note that you should generally be closing the `reader` in a `finally` block anyway, so that it gets closed even in the face of another exception.

See the [Java Tutorial lesson on exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) for more details about checked and unchecked exceptions.

Comment: I added throws to the method signature, but how would I include the finally block if I don't include try{}?

Comment: @JamesRoberts - You can use a `try/finally` structure (without any `catch` blocks). An alternative, if you're using Java 7, is to use a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

Comment: Also I am no longer getting errors within the method, however there is a `Unhandled Exception Type IOException` error on the method call.

Comment: @JamesRoberts - At some level in the call hierarchy you will need to deal with the exceptions that might arise from your code. It all goes back to Jon's question: what do you want to happen if there is an exception (for instance, if the file cannot be opened)?

Comment: @James: please read the tutorial as it will explain all and is better than trying to use tools without trying to first understand them.

Answer (score 2):

One solution: change to

```
private static void euler8() throws IOException {
```

But then the calling method has to catch the IOException.

or catch the Exception:

```
private static void euler8()
{   
    int c =0;
    int b;
    ArrayList<Integer> bar = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
    BufferedReader reader;
    try { 
        File inFile = new File("euler8.txt");
        reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream(infile), //###
                            Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        while((c = reader.read()) != -1) { //###
          char character = (char) c;
          b = (int)character;
          bar.add(b); /*When I add this line*/
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
       // LOG or output exception
       System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        try {
           reader.close(); //###
        } catch (IOException ignored) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap in a try/catch block to catch the Exceptions.

If you do not do that it will go unhandled.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you can't read the nominated file ? The `FileInputStream` will throw an exception and Java mandates that you'll have to check for this and handle it.

This type of exception is called a *checked* exception. *Unchecked* exceptions exist and Java doesn't require you to handle these (largely because they're unhandable - e.g. `OutOfMemoryException`)

Note that your handling may include catching it and ignoring it. This isn't a good idea, but Java can't really determine that :-)