# Catch error to end the printwriter

Tags: java, html, try-catch, finally

Hi i'm trying to create a program which will allow the user when run to choose whether they want the results i have on a separate file in plain text  the console or html on a web browser. The only error that seems to be appearing at the moment is that the catch should be a finally but if i change it to finally it never closes my printwriter. Thanks for any help.

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.FileWriter;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HTML {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        int scorehome = 0;
        int scoreaway = 0;
        int invalid = 0;
        int goals = 0;
        int valid = 0;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Do you want to generate plain (T)ext or (H)TML");

        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        boolean generateHTML = false;       

        if ( input.equalsIgnoreCase("H") ) {
            generateHTML = true;
        }
        String line;    // stores the each line of text read from the file

        PrintWriter online = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:/temp/htmloutput.html"));

        while ( scanner.hasNext() ) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();  // read the next line of text from the file

            //split the line
            String [] elements = line.split(":");


                //System.out.println("Element " + (i+1) + " was : " + elements[i]);
                if (elements.length == 4) {


                String home = elements[0].trim();
                String away = elements[1].trim();
                String homescore = elements[2].trim();
                String awayscore = elements[3].trim();

                boolean homescoreVal = false;
                boolean awayscoreVal = false;
                boolean homenameVal = false;
                boolean awaynameVal = false;

                    try {   // "try" is a special statement which allows us to deal with "exceptions"
                        scorehome = Integer.parseInt(homescore);    // attempt to convert the String into an Integer type value
                        homescoreVal = true;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        homescoreVal = false;
                    }
                    try {
                        scoreaway = Integer.parseInt(awayscore);    // attempt to convert the String into an Integer type value
                        awayscoreVal = true;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        homescoreVal = false;
                    }

                    if (home.length() <= 1) {
                        homenameVal = false;
                    } else {
                        homenameVal = true;
                    }

                    if (away.length() <= 1) {
                        awaynameVal = false;
                    } else {
                        awaynameVal = true;
                    }

                    if (homescoreVal == true && awayscoreVal == true
                            && homenameVal == true && awaynameVal == true){ 

                        System.out.println(home + " [" + scorehome + "] | "
                                + away + " [" + scoreaway + "]\r");



                    goals = (scorehome + scoreaway) + goals;

                    valid = 1 + valid;
                    } else {
                        invalid = 1 +invalid;
                    }

                }

                else {
                    invalid = 1 + invalid;
                }
            }

        System.out.println("\rValid match was " + valid);
        System.out.println("Total goals scored was " + goals);
        System.out.println("Invalid match count was " + invalid + ".");

        System.out.println("\nEOF");    // Output and End Of File message.

        if (generateHTML == true) {
            online.println("\rValid match was " + valid);
            online.println("Total goals scored was " + goals);
            online.println("Invalid match count was " + invalid + ".");
            }

        String locationOfFile = "C:\temp\\htmloutput.html";

        try { 
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start " + locationOfFile);

        }   catch {
            System.err.println("Error: unable to open " + locationOfFile);
            }
        }
    }
```

Error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete TryStatement

```
at HTML.main(HTML.java:117)
```

Comment: Can you plz post up your error message?

Comment: There are too many try catch block can you point out the error line?

Comment: @KickButtowski it's the very last catch at the end

Comment: You didn't specify which exception your last `catch` block will catch.

Comment: and I do not know if it is issuer or not but you close your last try block twice

Comment: @Davepop did you read rgettman comment and my comment after it?

Comment: I've edited it so that the error for the try goes away cause of how you said i closed it twice. Thanks. The error is the very catch at the end when it expects a finally. Its there to catch the printwriter at the very end

Comment: @Davepop    so everything is fine? did you do what rgettman told u ?

Comment: @KickButtowski sorry i'm just really confused cause i put it in to catch the printwriter at the very start so haven't i already specified the exception?

Comment: If you're confused, then read something about [`catch` blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)?

Comment: @Davepop where did you do that? can u show me?

Comment: @KickButtowski I added (NumberFormatException e) to the last catch which corrected the error but now has come up with the error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Unhandled exception type IOException
 Unhandled exception type IOException

 at HTML.main(HTML.java:31)

Comment: [Unhandled Exception: IOException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305966/why-do-i-get-the-unhandled-exception-type-ioexception). If you have problem, please do some research about it.

Comment: @Davepop wanna skype ?

Comment: @KickButtowski sorry for the late reply but i'd love to skype if the offers still open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have read your code, you code logic does not make sense and does not have the follow that you are looking for

You should seat and break down your issue to pieces

1. you need to figure out what is gonna happen if your user type H for choosing HTML or T for plain Text.

for example have this piece of code as your blue print

```
    System.out.println("Either enter t for plain text\n or h for HTML");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String  answer = input.nextLine();

    if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("H")){
        System.out.println("wowwwwww you chose HTML");

        }
    else if( answer.equalsIgnoreCase("T")){
        System.out.println("wowwwwww you chose plain text");
     }
}
```

2. After that you need to see what you want to do in each case, in general you can follow the follwing

   ```
     1. you gonnna read your file that you have how? using Scanner 
     2. when you have your data inside a array or whatever data structure 
     3. you gonna do your manipulation 
     4.the last job is to write back to wherever you wanna
   ```

Some Points you should know about the try catch block

1. you can have try block with finally block and without catch block
2. if something will go wrong in your try block, your catch block will inform you about your issue like

for example:

```
 try{
        System.out.print(7/0);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }finally{
        System.out.println("no matter what I gonna be executed");
    }
```

In your try block you try to dived a number which is seven by zero which throw an exception

3. your finally block will be executed no matter what as you see
4. if your try block works find your catch block never executed but again your finally block get executed
5. if something go wrong in your try block, other statements will not executed and you will go to your catch block if you have