# In Java EE how do I retrieve data from a site like Google Dictionary or Definition Lookup

Tags: java, api, dictionary, url, cpu-word

Okay, I'm a total noob to stack overflow so please forgive me if I do something wrong :3.

I am using java EE in eclipse mars and I would like to retrieve a response from a website like Definition Lookup or google dictionary (http://google-dictionary.so8848.com/).

From what I understand I would have to send a request through the URL using a format similar to this 
google-dictionary.so8848.com/meaning?word="Word to lookup"

What I don't know, or understand is how exactly to go about that, thanks in advance to anyone willing to answer this <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want here is called [web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping), you can accomplish that with multiple frameworks but I recommed [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) because it is the easiest one.

Here is a quick example using Jsoup:

**First**: [Download](https://jsoup.org/download) Jsoup jar file:

Or if you are using Maven add it to POM.xml

```
<dependency>
  <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
  <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**Second:**: Connect to website you want:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("google-dictionary.so8848.com/meaning?
word="Word to lookup"").get();
```

**Third**: Parse and find elements you want from the returning HTML:

```
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("Element you want");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, you saved my butt. One last quick question, how do I find the name of an element in an HTML page (I'm not particularly fluent in HTML and I only kind of know what that means)

Comment: You have two options, either select by tag name like: <div> div is the name or get it by unique value like(name, id, class) ex: <div id="id" name="name" class="class"> all of this using Css-like selectors ex:  
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("div[name=myname]");

Comment: oh wait one more thing, which document import should I be using, because I'm using the Jsoup one and it's throwing a fit (Unhandeled IOException error, which I have no clue what means)

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305966/why-do-i-get-the-unhandled-exception-type-ioexception) for details.